# SELECT JOIN WHERE a record does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables

```
id      name   type
1       aa     driver
2       bb     cyclist
3       cc     runner

parent_id      key      value
1              mobile   00299029
2              mobile   008772
2              active   1
3              mobile   09887
3              active   0
```

I need to get the record 1,aa,driver, the one that has not a record with value 'active' in the second table.
My last try was something like this, but I'n not sure to be even a bit close to what I need, my result is always 0 records

```
SELECT t1.name as name
FROM table1 as t1
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM table2
   WHERE key = 'active'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a left join would do

```
    SELECT t1.name as name
     FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 
       ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
      AND t2.key = 'active'
    WHERE t2.key IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select t1.name from table1 t1 
where not exists 
(
    select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.parent_id  AND t2.key = 'active'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I think, not entirely sure I understand the linkage):

```
SELECT t1.name as name
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id and t2.key = 'active' where t2.key is null
```

A `left join` returns all elements of the first table regardless of whether they have a corresponding record in the joined table. By then including `t2.key is null` in the `where` clause, you limit it to records that only exist in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT t1.name as name
FROM table1 as t1
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
AND t2.key  not like '%active%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think Your query is not working in this case, please try 
>   this

```
 SELECT name FROM table1 
 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = 
 table2.parent_id where id not IN ( SELECT parent_id 
 FROM 
table2 WHERE `key` = 'active' )
```

Comment: Why you used join and subquery together I dont understand ?

Comment: I changed the query according to the requirement , without changing what the user was trying to do. may be he/she needs join for the further operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id,name,type from table1 
where id Not in
(Select 
 parent_id from table2 
 group by parent_id 
 having key= 
 'active')
```

> Better avoid join in this case I would say as subquery 
>   would do good in this case.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.type,t2.key,t2.value
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
where t2.key <>'active'